# PostgreSQL how to find duplicates by aggregated value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. The *screenshots* with the following structure:

1. id (bigint)
2. originalFilename (string)
3. createdAt (Date)

And the second is *screenshotSignatures*:

1. screenshotId (foreign key for screenshots)
2. signature (bigint)

So the screenshots table has one to many relation. So now I need to find all duplicates. It means screenshot has exactly the same signatures. I tried to do following:

```
SELECT os.id, os."originalFilename", array_agg(signature) as signatures from "development".screenshots os
left join development."screenshotSignatures" s on os.id = s."screenshotId"
WHERE GROUP BY os.id, os."originalFilename" ;
```

and from this query I get the following result: [image]

So now I need to find out the duplicates somehow, but I don't know to do it. I thought I can do it some how from *screenshotSignatures* table. As a result it will be nice to have smth like: screenshots (a,b,c) have the same set of signatures. Later I'll need to delete the oldest screenshots. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
WITH signature_list AS (
  SELECT os.id, os."originalFilename", array_agg(signature ORDER BY signature) as signatures 
  from "development".screenshots os
  left join development."screenshotSignatures" s on os.id = s."screenshotId"
  GROUP BY os.id, os."originalFilename"
)
SELECT signatures, array_agg(id) as duplicate_ids, array_agg(originalFilename) as duplicate_filenames
FROM signature_list 
GROUP BY signatures
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it says: *Unable to resolve column signatures* in HAVING clause. Am I did smth wrong?

Comment: Okay, let's first aggregate the signatures for each filename - and then find duplicate signatures.

Comment: It sounds cool, but how to do it? Could you provide some code?

Comment: I updated my answer - it does the aggregation inside the CTE and then uses the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Thank you man! You're my hero!